# (Python) Using threading to look for key input with getch

Tags: python, multithreading, io

I've been trying to write a piece of test code which will continually print "Running" until a key is pressed. I've tried to implement this by creating an additional thread (called thread1) that will listen for a keypress.

When I run my code, the thread launches fine, and seems to execute properly until getch.getch() is called. While getch.getch() is waiting for a keypress, it seems to stop not only thread1, but also the main thread.

How can I ensure that while thread1 listens for a keypress, the main thread keeps running?

I'm using python 2.7 and getch 1.0 (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/getch).

Here's my code:

```
import threading
import time
import getch

class myThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name, cont):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name
        self.cont = cont

    def run(self):
        print "Starting " + self.name +"\n"
        print "waiting 2 seconds"
        time.sleep(2)
        char = getch.getch()
        print 'You pressed %s' % char
        cont.append(1)
        print "Terminating" + self.name

cont = []

thread1 = myThread(1, "Thread1", cont)

thread1.start()

while cont == []:
    print "Running"
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

It outputs this:

```
Starting Thread1
Running

waiting 2 seconds
Running
Running
Running
```

And it stays there until I press a key

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're hitting this issue because of the GIL. It works fine if you make the `threading.Thread` a `multiprocessing.Process`:

```
class myThread (multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name, cont):
        super(myThread, self).__init__()
        #threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name
        self.cont = contdef run(self):
        print "Starting " + self.name +"\n"
        char = getch.getch()
        print 'You pressed %s' % char
        cont.append(1)
        print "Terminating" + self.name

cont = []

thread1 = myThread(1, "Thread1", cont)

thread1.start()

while cont == []: 
    print "Running"
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Output:

```
dan@dantop:~$ ./get.py 
Running
Starting Thread1

Running
Running
Running
Running
Running
Running
Running
Running
You pressed f
TerminatingThread1
Running
Running
Running
Running
Running
Running
Running
Running
```

`getch` is a C-extension, and is doing a blocking call to `getchar()`, but it doesn't release the GIL first. Because Python cannot actually run two threads concurrently, it gets stuck in the worker thread waiting for blocking call to `getchar()`.

You can actually fix this bug pretty easily, by explicitly releasing the GIL from the `getch` C-extension code, using `Py_BEGIN_THREADS` and `Py_ALLOW_THREADS`:

```
static PyObject *getch_getche(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    int ok = PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "");
    char c;
    Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS
    c = getche();
    Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS
    return PyUnicode_FromFormat("%c", c); 
}

static PyObject *getch_getch(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    int ok = PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "");
    char c;
    Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS
    c = getch();
    Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS
    return PyUnicode_FromFormat("%c", c); 
}
```

If you make that change to `getchmodule.c` and rebuild the extension, the original, thread-using, example code works fine.

Comment: Its probably hitting the gil because getch is a blocking system level call not a blocking python call ... raw_input is a python call that blocks(but its a python level call) and works fine but i think getch blocks from an os level rather than python

Comment: Perfect! That did the trick. Although it's not breaking the loop as it should, but that's a separate issue. Thank You!

Comment: @JoranBeasley yes, that's correct. It's blocking in a C-extension without releasing the GIL. I updated my answer to explain that and how to fix it if desired.