# How To Make Two Threads Run At the Same Time In Python?

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to make two functions run at the same time. One of the functions downloads a bunch of files from a server, the other changes the text of a label in the gui that acts as a progress bar. The thread doing the downloading seems to be completely preventing the other thread from running until after it finishes, even though the other thread is started first. Here is the code:

```
def getData(statusText):
    getFiles = threading.Thread(target=mf.getCurrentData)
    progressDisplay = threading.Thread(target=progressBar, args=(statusText,))
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        progressDisplay.start()
        getFiles.start()
```

EDIT: When I try to use multiprocessing, I recieve the following error: PicklingError: Can't pickle 'tkapp' object:

EDIT 2: After trying everything to get multiprocessing to work, it appears as though that is simply not an option for me. In order to make it update the GUI, I would have to extensively modify the existing code. I do not understand why threading does not work however. Another part of my program IS working with the threading, and the process being run a long side the progress bar takes significantly more memory in that instance.

EDIT 3: I solved the problem. It was really stupid on my part. A loop somewhere else in the program was preventing the thread from running correctly. I kept using thread instead of multiprocessing, since I am passing tkinter objects to the threads.

Comment: try using multiprocessing instead... you are seeing this because however you are downloading the page is blocking at a lower level than python ... and the GIL prevents python from continuing ... the other option is to release the pythong GIL in the c source of whatever you are using to download

Comment: If you're just using `start()`, you can pretty much drop in `multiprocessing.Process` in place of `threading.Thread` -- Joran's right in that this will at least alleviate the GIL problems.

Comment: good tut on multiprocessing here http://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/communication.html

Comment: Evil answer: `import Tkinter; Tk.eval("package require Thread")` and than use native Tcl threads that don't suffer from a GIL..., just joking. But in general, your code should work, even in Python with a GIL, unless you have C code on board that blocks without releasing the GIL. If you use swig, try the `-thread` switch...

Comment: isn't fetching a web page IO bound? Why would the GIL matter in this case? I'm not sure what progressDisplay does but I suspect it could be rewritten to involve minimal CPU requirements?

Comment: @Rohit there is almost certainly a call to some c library that is not releasing the gil while downloading the page... since the gil is not released the thread wont switch  (here is a recent question that has essentially the same problem, different input method though http://stackoverflow.com/a/24192482/541038)

Comment: @a p I tried using multiprocessing originally, but I got a pickling error that had something to do with the fact I am using Tkinter.

Comment: Are you using tkinter? Some other GUI toolkit? It would help if you mentioned that in the question, and added the appropriate tag.